# Talend Casting of JSON string to JSON or JSONB in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, talend

I'm trying to use Talend to get JSON data that is stored in MySQL as a VARCHAR datatype and export it into PostgreSQL 9.4 table of the following type:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable( myJSON as JSONB)
```

When I try running the job I get the following error:

> ERROR: column "json_string" is of type json but expression is of type
>   character varying
>
> Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.   Position:
>   54

If I use python or just plain SQL with PostgreSQL insert I can insert a string such as '{"Name":"blah"}' and it understands it.

```
INSERT INTO myTable(myJSON) VALUES ('{"Name":"blah"}');
```

Any Idea's how this can be done in Talend?

Comment: I came across the same kind of error but not for json though. The problem/limitation is Talend doesn't supportr JSONB data type. As the hint suggests either you have to type cast or change the data type in your postgress table. I do this kind of typecasting using tSplitRow component.

Comment: @JaiPrakash How do you use that component to cast to a different type?

Comment: @exhuma please my answer below. hope the images are visible and makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a type-cast by opening the "Advanced Settings" tab on you "tPostgresqlOutput" component. Consider the following example:

In this case, the input row to "tPostgresqlOutput_1" has one column `data`. This column is of type `String` and is mapped to the database column `data` of type `VARCHAR` (as by the default suggested by Talend):

[image: tPostgreslOutput_1 schema]

Next, open the component settings for `tPostgresqlOutput_1` and locate the "Advanced settings" tab:

[image: Advanced Settings Tab]

On this tab, you can **replace** the existing `data` column by a new expression:

- In the *name* column, specify the target column name.
- In the *SQL Expression* column, do your type casting. In this case: `` "?::json"`. Note the usage of the placeholder character ``?`` which will be replaced with the original value.
- In *Position*, specify `Replace`. This will replace the value proposed by Talend with your SQL expression (including the type cast).
- As *Reference Column* use the source value.

[image: Type Casting]

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. Worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is a sample schema for where in i have the input row 'r' which has question_json and choice_json columns which are json strings. From which i know the key what i wanted to extract and here is how i do

[image]

you should look at the columns question_value and choice_value. Hope this helps you

Comment: This is unfortunately not an answer to the question. You are showing how to *read* JSON from a DB. What I am looking for is how to *write* JSON to a DB. Or to be more general: How can I typecast a value when writing to the DB (which is needed in this  case). I added a solution I found as answer which works well. I'm leaving this unaccepted for now in case someone finds a better solution.